# Inconsistent results when checking for Null values (Jet DAO vs. ACE DAO)

Tags: ms-access, vb6, dao, jet

In a VB6 program accessing an MDB file, the following SQL query is being executed:

```
> Select * FROM [table1] WHERE ([type] = 1 OR [type] = 2 OR [type] = 6)
> AND ([notes] = Null OR [notes] = '0') AND [date] >= 
> cvdate('09/03/2013') ORDER BY [date], [column2]
```

If I reference `Microsoft Access 14.0 Object Library` in the program the returned recordset has `0` rows.

If I reference `Microsoft DAO 3.51 Object Library` the returned recordset has over `100` rows.

What is the reason for this difference?  Is there a difference between the way the two providers handles the test for `Null`?  Is this a breaking change for ACE DAO accessing older MDB files?

Answer (score 7):

`WHERE ... [notes] = Null` is non-standard SQL. [Null propagation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29#Null_propagation) can potentially force any expression involving `Null` to return `Null`. Therefore the expression `[notes] = Null` (which you intended to be a boolean expression) could very well return `Null`, which is neither `True` nor `False`.

How the query processor handles that `Null` value may indeed differ from one database engine to another: it could interpret `Null` as `False`, or it could just ignore the result, or it could trigger an error. Note also that null propagation could collapse your entire WHERE clause to `Null` if...

`(some other condition) AND (Null)`

...evaluates to `Null`.

Standard SQL would be `([notes] IS NULL)` and a Jet/ACE equivalent would be `IsNull([notes])`. Both of these will always return either `True` or `False`.

Answer (score 1):

DAO 3.51 is way outdated.  It was replaced by DAO 3.6 many years ago.  Use 3.6 instead and then see whether this version of your query returns the same results from both DAO 3.6 and ACEDAO:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM [table1]
WHERE
        [type] IN (1,2,6)
    AND ([notes] Is Null OR [notes] = '0')
    AND [date] >= cvdate('09/03/2013')
ORDER BY [date], [column2];
```